# Can you Integrate Temenos Quantum (Kony Mobile Fabric) onto a flutter application?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, temenos-quantum, temenos

Temenos Quantum or Kony mobile fabric is a platform that can be used to create and integrate backend for applications, it is primarily used in conjunction with temenos visualizer to develop hybrid applications that can run on multiple platforms.

My question is that is it possible to integrate kony mobile fabric onto a flutter codebase, either through an SDK or a Library and develop multi-platform applications while using kony mobile fabric for its backend.

Answer (score 0):

Technically possible, since quantum fabric produces the json API to front end and using API key and secret, you can access the same.

So using GetXservice in the flutter, i believe technically no concern on accessing the fabric API, but i never tried ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, you should just make sure that the "Operation Security Level" of the API (Service definition operation) available though the Quantum Fabric is set to Public.

If you set it to "Auhtenticated App User" for example, will compplexify the process.

Cordially,
Hervé N.